# How to show that a set $D\subset R^2$ is not connected using a continuous function $F:R^2\mapsto R$

Tags: general-topology

We have $$F:R^{2}\rightarrow R  ,   F\left( x,y\right) =x^{3}+2x^{2}y+y^{3}$$ and for $D\subset R^{2}$  we know      $$0\in F\left( D\right),4\in F\left( D\right) \text {but } 2\not\in F\left( D\right)$$
How to show that $D$ is not a connected set?

Comment: Anything tried so far? You sure mean $F:\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R$, don't you?

Comment: $f$ is obviously continuous, so if we restrict its domain to $D$ but we can find $a,b\in D$ so that $f(a)=0,f(b)=4$, then if $D$ was connected we could find a path $\Gamma$ in $D$ connecting $a,b$ and $f$ would be continuous along the path.

Comment: @almagest, a set can be connected without being path connected.

Comment: I did some editing on your question, if you feel something went wrong feel free to revert back to your original question or let me know

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use that F? The first thing that came to my mind was to use a locally constant function: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant. Maybe there is a way to reduce the problem to this?

Comment: @William All you know about $D$ is implicitly given by the image of $F$, so you sort of need to use this particularly $F$ to gain information about $D$

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a general theorem that [the continuous image of a connected set is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected).  The polynomial function $F$ is certainly continuous, while the stipulated conditions $0,4\in F(D)$ but $2\not\in F(D)$ imply the image $F(D)$ is *not* connected:  That is, $F(D)$ is covered by the union of *disjoint* open intervals $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)$ but not by either open interval by itself.  Thus $D$ cannot be connected.