# Connected Set in $ {R}^{2} $

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is $A=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ 
is  connected in $ℝ^2$?

From its graph, I would conclude that it's not path connected.

Comment: Isn't that just $S^1$, which can be identified with $[0, 2\pi) \subseteq \mathbb R$?  My topology is a bit rusty but that's what comes to mind.

Comment: What is your definition of connected? And what does the graph look like?

Comment: It's connected, the easiest way to see this is to use what @tilper have given you, it is the continuous image of $[0,2\pi)$ which is also connected.

Comment: @Servaes the graph is boundary of unit circle

Comment: @Sandy which is clearly connected in the plain english sense of the word. So that makes me wonder what your definition is, and why you think it isn't path connected.

Comment: @Sandy perhaps you're confusing *connected* with *convex*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
A = \left\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \right\} = \left\{(x,y) : x = \cos \theta, y =  \sin \theta, 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi\right\}
$$

The interval $\Theta = \left[0,2\pi \right)$ is connected, since $A$ is image of continuous map defined on a connected set then it is also connected (as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected))

Comment: thanks. @user8469759 if $A=\{(x,y):xy=1\}$, then this is connected in same way ?

Comment: No, that one isn't connected. Pick $(x,y) = (1,1)$ and $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$ there's no path joining these two points.

Comment: The trick I've used anyway is the observe that your set can be seen as an image of some function defined on some set.