# Is the smoothness required in the following question?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness, smooth-functions

Is the smoothness required in the following question ? I think continuity is sufficient to prove the function being continuous.

[image]

**My attempt:**

As $g$ is  a smooth function , $g$ will also be a continuous function.

Now if $g$  was not a constant function , it would have taken two values $1 , -1$.  So $g^{-1}(-1 )$  and $g^{-1}(1 )$  are two disjoint open sets of $S$. Besides , $g^{-1}(1) \cup g^{-1}(-1) = S$ as the co-domain set of $g$ contains only $1 , -1$.

So $S$  is not connected.

But it is given that $S$ is a connected surface of $\mathbb R^n$.

Therefore , $g$ is a constant function.

Comment: I think I agree. (Also weird to phrase the question as "tak[ing] on only" the values $1$ and $-1$, when they mean has range contained in $\{-1, 1\}$.  I mean, it doesn't take both values on, does it?)  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected

Comment: Yes I know. That is the point. As $S$ is a connected surface , it will be a constant function.@leslietownes

Comment: please check my attempt@leslietownes

Comment: looks good to me.