# The set of inner products of two convex sets convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are compact and convex. Define $S=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\in X, y\in Y\} $. Is $S$ convex?

I tried to prove by taking an arbitrary convex combination of two elements in $S$ and tried to show it is also in $S$ but I got nowhere. I don't even know if the statement is true. Is it true? If so, any hint on how to prove it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is phrased unnecessarily complicated because the convex sets within $\mathbb R$ are specifically the *intervals* $(a,b), [a,b), (a,b], [a,b]$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: ...where $a$ might be$-\infty$ and $b$ might be $+\infty$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true, and it suffices that $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are *connected.* (This is more general since all convex sets in $\Bbb R^n$ are connected.)

Then $X \times Y$ is also connected (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338027/42969)) and the image of $X \times Y$ under the continuous function $f(x, y) = \langle x,y\rangle$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb R$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573795/42969)).

The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are exactly the intervals, and intervals are convex sets.

If, in addition, both $X$ and $Y$ are compact then $S$ is a compact interval, i.e. $S = [a, b]$ with real number $a \le b$.

Comment: Convex sets in $\mathbb R^n$ are always connected, aren't they?

Comment: @nelynx: Yes, but connected sets are not necessarily convex. What I wanted to express is that the condition “Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are compact and convex” can be relaxed.

Comment: I would add that to the answer (since the question originally asks for convex sets), but yeah, that is the best argument

Comment: @MartinR Beautiful! It is a world different from the brute force approach I was trying. Your answer just made my day, thank you so much.